# setting attribute value to its array key in php

Tags: php, arrays, key, set

(after deleting an XML node) the following gets a list of <picture> 'id' attribute values:

```
$objXML = new SimpleXMLElement(XML_FILE_NAME, null, true);
$picture = $objXML->xpath('picture');
$arrayCurrent = array();
foreach($picture as $value) {
    $arrayCurrent[] = (string)$value['id'];
}
sort($arrayCurrent); // required as XML nodes not in numerical 'id' order
print_r($arrayCurrent);
```

Which returns the following:

**Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 )**

I want to set each id to the value of its current key like so:

**Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 6 [7] => 7 )**

I've been messing about with this for a while but I wondered if there is a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you explicitly assign index keys and use [asort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php), I think you'll get what you want.</strike>

```
...
foreach($picture as $value) {
    $arrayCurrent[$value['id']] = (string)$value['id'];
}
asort($arrayCurrent); // required as XML nodes not in numerical 'id' order
...
```

Second try.. still not sure I understand you, but hey :) Instead of the foreach loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($picture); $i++)
{
  $picture[$i]['id'] = $i;
  $arrayCurrent[$i] = $i; // Not sure why you'd still want this, in this case.
}
```

Comment: Hmm, on a second thought, I think I might have misunderstood. You want to actually change the DOM elements to give them whatever key they are assigned when added to the array. Sorry!

Comment: Basically I have an XML file to which new nodes are added and given a new id number = (number of current nodes+1). In my example I deleted a node (id 4), then if I add a new node it will be given 'id 8', it would cause conflict with previous node already with id of 8. So each time I delete a node I must also re-index the id's.

Comment: Updated my answer.. any better? :)

Comment: Updated code seemed to be more like what I needed. I'm finding that the element with the highest ID in the array gets its ID changed to that of the deleted ID. Maybe I should post my updated code...

Comment: created a new question to hopefully explain it better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157494/reordering-array-attributes-then-save-back-to-xml-in-php